# How to filter an array of objects based on another array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, filter

I have two array of objects like below

```
conditions= [
          {
            'condition': 'Expert',
            'value': 'All'
          },
          {
            'condition': 'Coach',
            'value': 'willaim'
          },
          {
            'condition': 'manager',
            'value': 'Brandy Lovings'
          },
          {
            'condition': 'site',
            'value': 'ALL'
          },
          {
            'condition': 'client',
            'value': 'ALL'
          }
        ]

data=[
{
          "Date": "11/6/2018",
          "client": "Verizon",
          "Expert": "Ellison, Lauren",
          "Coach": "willaim",
          "manager": "Brandy Lovings",
          "site": "Sundance",
          "Metric": "STR"
        },
{
          "Date": "11/6/2018",
          "client": "Amzaon",
          "Expert": "Ellison, Lauren",
          "Coach": "Dash Williamson",
          "manager": "David",
          "site": "abc",
          "Metric": "STR"
        }
]
```

I want to filter data array with the conditions array, like if condition property in conditions array contain Expert then I need to filter data array based on `data.Expert = conditions[Expert Conditionindex].value` then I need to return all the data with this conditions.

Another thing is, If `value: 'ALL'` then no need of filtering in that particular condition.

The desired output is like

```
filteredData = [
{
              "Date": "11/6/2018",
              "client": "Verizon",
              "Expert": "Ellison, Lauren",
              "Coach": "willaim",
              "manager": "Brandy Lovings",
              "site": "Sundance",
              "Metric": "STR"
            }
]
```

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You could filter with a subset of conditions without `ALL` flag.

```js
var conditions = [{ condition: "Expert", value: "All" }, { condition: "Coach", value: "willaim" }, { condition: "manager", value: "Brandy Lovings" }, { condition: "site", value: "ALL" }, { condition: "client", value: "ALL" }],
    data = [{ Date: "11/6/2018", client: "Verizon", Expert: "Ellison, Lauren", Coach: "willaim", manager: "Brandy Lovings", site: "Sundance", Metric: "STR" }, { Date: "11/6/2018", client: "Amzaon", Expert: "Ellison, Lauren", Coach: "Dash Williamson", manager: "David", site: "abc", Metric: "STR" }],
    filters = conditions.filter(({ value }) => value.toUpperCase() !== 'ALL'),
    result = data.filter(o =>
        filters.every(({ condition, value }) => o[condition] === value));
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
    const conditionsObj={}

    conditions.filter(({value})=>value.toLowerCase()!=='all').forEach((condition)=>{
          conditionsObj[condition.condition]=condition.value
        })



     const results=data.filter((item)=>{
              let match=false;  
             Object.keys(conditionsObj).forEach((_key)=>{
                if(conditionsObj[_key]===item[_key]){
                  match=true;
                }
              })
              return match;
            })

console.log(results)
```